# class template specialization for linked list char*

Tags: c++, template-specialization

I have the following class:

```
template<class T>
struct Node {
    Node<T>* next;
    T data;
};

template<class T>
class LinkedList
{
private:
    Node<T>* first;
    Node<T>* last;
public:
    LinkedList<T>() : first(NULL), last(NULL) {}
    LinkedList<T>(const LinkedList& other)
    {
        operator=(other);
    }

    ~LinkedList()
    {
        Node<T>* tmp = first->next;
        while (!first)
        {
            tmp = first;
            first = first->next;
            free(tmp);  
        }
    }

    void add(const T& data) {
        Node<T>* tmp = new Node<T>;
        tmp->data = data;
        tmp->next = NULL;
        if (!first) {
            first = tmp;
            last = first;
        }
        else
        {
            last->next = tmp;
            last = tmp;
        }
    }

    Node<T>* getFirst() const
    {
        return first;
    }

    LinkedList<T>& operator=(const LinkedList<T>& other)
    {
        Node<T>* tmp = other.first;
        while (tmp)
        {
            add(tmp->data);
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    LinkedList<T>& operator-=(T value)
    {
        while (first && first->data == value)
        {
            Node<T>* tmp = first;
            first = first->next;
            free(tmp);
        }

        for (Node<T>* curr = first; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next)
        {
            while (curr->next != NULL && curr->next->data == value)
            {
                Node<T>* tmp = curr->next;
                if (tmp == last)
                {
                    last = curr;
                }
                curr->next = tmp->next;
                free(tmp);
            }
        }

        return *this;
    }

    LinkedList<T>& operator+=(const T& value)
    {
        add(value);
        return *this;
    }

    T get(int index) {
        if (index == 0) {
            return this->first->data;
        }
        else {
            Node<T>* curr = this->first;
            for (int i = 0; i < index; ++i) {
                curr = curr->next;
            }
            return curr->data;
        }
    }

    T operator[](int index) {
        return get(index);
    }

    bool isInList(T value)
    {
        Node<T>* tmp = first;
        while (tmp)
        {
            if (tmp->data == value)
                return true;
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        return false;
    }   
        
};
```

This current template implementation does not support the `char*` type, so I want to add a template specialization for the char* type.

Adding the following specialization:

```
template <>
LinkedList<char*>& LinkedList<char*>::operator+=(const char*& value)
{

}
```

gives the following error:

```
Error   C2244   'LinkedList<char *>::operator +=': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You have bigger problems tto worry about than how to implement this particular specialization. The copy constructor is completely broken and will result in likely crashes or memory corruption.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik id be happy if you can elaborate

Comment: If you use your debugger to set a breakpoint in the assignment operator, and use the copy constructor, then inspect the resulting copied linked list, node by node, the problem should be fairly obvious (you will find an obvious problem in the last node, if the assignment operator doesn't crash outright).

Comment: @S.M.: We can (fully) specialize just a method.

Comment: @Jarod42 How can I achieve this?

Comment: `List` should not have specialization for `char*`.

Comment: @Jarod42 std::string then?

Comment: @Jarod42 I need to check the current implementation for different data types, including char*

Comment: There are no need of specific code. code can really be generic.

Comment: @Jarod42 How? how will you compare char* with each other or copy their content?

Comment: You can compare pointer, if you want custom comparison (to allow to compare c-string content), provide comparer as template:  `template<class T, class Comparer = std::equal_to<T>> class LinkedList;`